# Failed at step EXEC spawning: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, services, systemd

Given the following one-shot service, enabled at boot,

```
[Unit]

Description = My Server Daemon
Documentation = https://etcetc.org

Wants = network-online.target getty.target NetworkManager-wait-online.service isc-dhcp-server.service xinetd.service smbd.service
After = network-online.target getty.target NetworkManager-wait-online.service isc-dhcp-server.service xinetd.service smbd.service

[Service]

Type = oneshot

RemainAfterExit = yes

User = foouser

PIDFile = /run/myd.pid

WorkingDirectory = /home/foouser/my-server/bin

ExecStart = /home/foouser/my-server/bin/myd
ExecStop = /home/foouser/my-server/bin/abort.sh

TimeoutStopSec = 5

[Install]

WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

It actually fails to start. Filtering `/var/log/syslog`

> systemd[1]: myd.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /home/foouser/my-server/bin/my: No such file or directory

While `journalctl --unit=myd.service` agrees

> systemd[1]: myd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR

So, since `/home/foouser/my-server/bin/myd` is a soft link of mine to `/home/foouser/my-server/xspyctra/xspyctrad.py`, I

1. changed `ExecStart = /home/foouser/my-server/xspyctra/xspyctrad.py`
2. commented *WorkingDirectory* in which I'm not actually interested, since the python script will do a `os.chdir('/home/foouser/my-server/bin')` by its own

Services reloaded, system rebooted, etc. But now I'm stunned from the following error

> systemd[1653]: myd.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/foouser/my-server/xspyctra/xspyctrad.py: No such file or directory
>
> systemd[1]: myd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC

I can grant for sure that that file exists

```
$ ls -l /home/foouser/my-server/xspyctra/xspyctrad.py
-rwxrw-r-- 1 foouser foouser 5532 May 10 16:13 /home/foouser/my-server/xspyctra/xspyctrad.py
```

As a last diagnostic, `service myd status`

```
● myd.service - My Server Daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-05-11 10:58:21 CEST; 16min ago
  Docs: https://etcetc.org
  Main PID: 1627 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

## EDIT 1

However, this could somehow happens only during boot time. As a matter of fact,

```
sudo service myd stop
sudo service myd start
```

seems working, because `service myd status`

```
● myd.service - My Server Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2018-05-11 11:22:52 CEST; 1min 16s ago
       Docs: https://etcetc.org
   Main PID: 2106 (python2)
      Tasks: 24
     Memory: 545.1M
        CPU: 10.913s
     CGroup: /system.slice/myd.service
       ├─2106 python2 /home/foouser/my-server/bin/myd
       ├─2122 ./<my-child-process-a>
       ├─2127 ./<my-child-process-b>
       └─2133 ./<my-child-process-c>
```

As expected.
Furthermore, notice that `xspyctrad.py`, the actual script, will spawn a `twisted.reactor`, hence will not return and stay in foreground.

So where could be my mistake ?

Comment: Are you sure `/home/` is mounted when the unit runs at startup? Is your `/home/foouser/` encrypted maybe? There's also `ProtectHome=` option but I *guess* if it was the problem then the last example would fail.

Comment: Yes, `/home/foouser/` is encrypted. So guess is better to install everything inside `/usr/bin/`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides moving executables to an early-accessible location (which is anyway a good thing to do), it is possible specify mount dependencies to tell systemd to delay start-up of your unit until after the location is mounted and available.

You can either use [`RequiresMountsFor=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=):

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/home/foouser/my-server/bin
```

Or specify [`Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=)/[`After=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) on a corresponding [`.mount` unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html), if you know exactly *what* needs to be mounted:

```
[Unit]
Requires=home-foouser.mount
After=home-foouser.mount
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kamil pointed out, `/home/foouser/` does not exist at the time service started. Moving to an existing location closed the issue.