# systemctl service doesn't start

Tags: linux, systemctl

I have made a service for my RaspBerryPi project.
When I start it nothing happens. `systemctl status sb.service` returns this:

```
Failed to start RPI-sound board.
Unit entered failed state.
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

sb.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=RPI-sound board
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/RPSB/RpiSoundBoard.sh
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The files that it is supposed to run are [hosted here](https://github.com/MaticBabnik/RPI-Soundboard). They run just fine if I run them myself.
How can I get more output from my service / or fix this?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1321750/432690). If not a duplicate, at least you'll find few diagnostic commands there.

Comment: Simple [edit] here to add the below detail from the answer you may have accidentally  provided below and then delete the below answer if that's not what you intended to do here.

Comment: Consider running `chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/RPSB/RpiSoundBoard.sh` too just in case to confirm it's not a permission issue executing the sh script.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/Desktop/RPSB/soundPlayer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ._xorg import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pynput._util.xorg import (
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 40, in <module>
    _check()
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 38, in _check
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 84, in __init__
    name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 73, in get_display
    return mod.get_display(display)
    File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_display
    error.DisplayNameError(display)
    Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

Comment: So you found some log detail but this does not answer your question, right? What is the fix you applied if this is meant to be an answer? You might consider editing the original question you wrote above and then delete this answer. Otherwise add the parts to show the fix/solution to your question.